# If $(N,\|.\|)$ is a non trivial vector space with norm, then the diameter of the unit sphere is $\ge2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

It is easy to see that $\delta(B_1(0))\le 2$ because $$\|x-y\|\le\|x\|+\|-y\|=\|x\|+|-1|\|y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|<1+1=2$$
 so $\sup\{\|x-y\|:x,y\in B_1(0)\}\le 2$

But to show that $\delta(B_1(0))\ge 2$ we chose $a\in B_1(0)\backslash\{0\}$ and $s\in[0,1)$ and observe that $\|s\frac{a}{\|a\|}\|=s$ $\implies s\frac{a}{\|a\|},-s\frac{a}{\|a\|}\in B_1(0)$ and $\|s\frac{a}{\|a\|}-(-s\frac{a}{\|a\|})\|=2s$

But why does that imply that $\delta(B_1(0))\ge2s$?

This is how I think I understand it: the diameter of $B_1(0)$ is greater than that of $B_s(0)$ for all $s\in[0,1)$ because we it contains it. And the diameter of $B_s(0)$ is $2s$ for each $s$, which is true because there exists a sequence $(\epsilon_n\frac{a}{\|a\|},-\epsilon_n\frac{a}{\|a\|})$ of pairs of points, with $0\le\epsilon_n<s~\forall n$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\epsilon_n=s$ such that it is always contained in $B_s(0)$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}d(\epsilon_n\frac{a}{\|a\|},-\epsilon_n\frac{a}{\|a\|})=2s$

I'm not sure if I got it right...

Comment: "But why does that imply that $\delta(B_1(0))\geq 2s$?" - because it has two things in it that are $2s$ apart. That's it.

Comment: Well if $d(x,y)=2$ then that would imply $\|x\|=\|y=-x\|=1\not<1\implies x\notin B_1(0)$, but I'm not sure how to prove that

$\|\pm\frac{a}{\|a\|}\|=1$ so $\pm\frac{a}{\|a\|}\notin B_1(0)$

Comment: I am sorry, I realize you are speaking of the open ball. In that case, my argument was wrong. However,  you are right : for every $s \in [0,1)$, we can find two elements in $B_1(0)$ which have distance $2s$  from each other. This shows that the diameter of $B_1(0)$ is at least $2s$ for every $s \in [0,1)$ , and hence at least $2$. Note that no two points inside $B_1(0)$ have distance two between each other, but then the diameter does not require this to occur : if the diameter of a set $S$ is $d$, then it means that there are two points in $S$ separated by $d-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You suppose that you can choose $s\in [0,1)$ as near to 1 as you want, but it isn't generally true in a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space.
Consider for example a $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$-vector space, than $B_{1}(0)=\{0\}$.
That's why in general the statement is false.

Anyway, i think your proof works in every $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$-vector space